# NextJs not showing proper page on load (showing / )

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js

I'm using nextJs on aws s3 and the site works all for one element : when I access directly the url /blog for example, nextJs doesn't show the proper page, it shows the /index instead of /blog.

How can I debug that and correct the issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the console and/or the network log in your browser: probably there’s some kind of HTTP error and you have configured S3 to use index.html as error page.

**UPDATE**: the problem was a bad mapping on the /blog route

Comment: I see "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()", in that case s3 is configured to redirect to /index, but how can I get a 200 response ?

Comment: It’s clearly a bug in your application that you must fix.

Comment: I don't see a bug in my app at this point, can you be specific ? about either finding the bug, or what kind of bug It can be? Thanks

Comment: A 404 means that the route you’re asking for is non existent: you should check your route configuration or, if the path you’re pointing to is a physical path (and not a virtual one managed by your NextJS app), you should check if the resource exists. You could also check if you are pointing to an hardcoded path somewhere, that is causing the 404.

Comment: The path exists in the app, and when I'm redirected to the /index I can click on the link and it works, I see the page and everything is ok. What doesn't work is when I hit /blog than I'm redirected on /

Comment: So the problem is on the /blog path. I don’t know NextJS, but I guess that somewhere you should configure the routing for the /blog path that should instantiate some component/module/page. Have you tried to debug on a local env?

Comment: I got it ! Lol, the real path is /blog.html and I'm accessing /blog, so files needs to be renamed in some way for it to work. I got it working by direct access to /blog.html. Thanks for ur help !!